# Do Evangelicals think you have to be saved every day?

Tags: evangelicalism, conversion

Why does my brother in law tell us that we have to accept Jesus every time he talks to me, my children or his brother? He has known me for 36 years. He knows that I am saved, that I brought the children up to believe, and that they also accepted Jesus as their savior. When he talks to my children (35, 34 and 32) he makes them accept Jesus every time.

He has not done this to me in the 36 years that I have been married to his brother.  But his brother my husband passed away in October.  I continually have a relationship with Jesus and pray every day that if he would talk to me or ask me, I would tell him even though he should already know. This Christmas he sent me a letter and pamphlets to accept Jesus as my savior. I was talking to my children as I couldn't believe that after 36 years, and being included in all the children's accepting Jesus in the church, he would say that.

My children think that because he is an evangelist he believes that you have to be saved every day. That when he talks to them he makes them recite that they are asking Jesus to come into their life. They said he has always done this ever since they could remember. I know we are sinners and Jesus knows too. I confess and ask for forgiveness in my own relationship with Jesus.

**Are evangelicals supposed to be saved every day or more than 1 time a day?**

Comment: I have never heard of this and there is no single text in scripture that supports this behaviour. In my view it is based on a legalistic attitude and the concept that mankind can save itself by its own works. You are welcome to view my profile and the information contained therein, but the site, generally, discourages offering 'personalized advice' as it is an academic site. If your question stays open, and I hope it does, I shall answer your question, in due course. Up-voted +1.

Comment: That sounds awful, yet could you please re-write the exposition to leave out at least most of the purely personal details?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to Robbie Goodwin.  It only shows my 1st name doesn't even provide the state or where I am from.  Does not have any names, or any other identifying information.  Please if you see something that provides personal or any identifying any information please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a theological difference that might mean he doesn't believe you are truly Christian? Eg are you Catholic and he Protestant, or you Mormon and he JW?

Comment: Maybe it's a misinterpretation of Luke 9:23 'Then He said to them all, “If anyone desires to come after Me, let him deny himself, and _take up his cross daily_, and follow Me.' We should each bear our cross on a daily basis. We should each crucify the flesh daily. Nowhere that I've ever seen says we should ask for salvation daily.

Comment: Lamentations 3:22-25. // 22 Because of the Lord’s great love we are not consumed,
    for his compassions never fail.
23 They are new every morning;
    great is your faithfulness.
24 I say to myself, “The Lord is my portion;
    therefore I will wait for him.”
25 The Lord is good to those whose hope is in him,
    to the one who seeks him.

Comment: theological has never been an issue, he has attended my Methodist Church in the with no issues.  He also knows that I am not happy with the new doctrine of the Methodist Church.  In my thank you letter to him after my husband passed in October that I said my heart is broken in so many pieces and I hurt from the loss but picking up the pieces and following the path God has for me.  He responded by saying many women in his church are widows and have been saved and no longer suffer pain and he sent me a pamphlet to be saved.  I do not know if Evangelist pastors go to seminary and are ordained.

Answer (score 6):

It is true that many scriptures exhort us to spiritual exercises on a daily basis : prayer, worship and the care of our fellow human beings.

And it is true that Jesus Christ himself exhorts to continued and increased devotion and maturity in the faith. I am thinking, here, of the seven letters written to seven churches which express deep concern for the daily walk and pilgrimage of every member of the body of Christ.

But no scripture I can think of and no group or gathering I have ever come into contact with, in the past fifty five years of my own Christian profession (I am in my seventies) has ever expressed the need of being 'saved every day' nor have I ever read, in Church history, of such a doctrine.

This undermines the work of God in the soul. It undermines justification by faith, which is God's work (to justify) and the Holy Spirit's work (to bring to repentance and to faith).

We are not saved by works, by decisions, by assertions, by acceptances nor by commitments or promises or oaths or covenants of our own.

> ... For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that **not of yourselves**: it is the gift of God: [Ephesians 2:8 KJV]

Those who have repented, who have believed the gospel of Jesus Christ, the Son of God, who have been publicly baptised, and who 'continue in the apostles' doctrine and fellowship and in breaking of bread and prayers', Acts 2:42, have ' *already been delivered* from the wrath to come' , 1 Thessalonians 1:10, and we look, in hope and in love, for his promised return.

---

I was baptised into the presbyterian Church of Scotland at the age of five (I remember the event) and I volunteered for baptism, again, as an adult, at the age of sixteen, into the Baptist Assembly of Scotland. I am now independent of any denomination.

My evangelical testimony, written at the age of twenty-one in 1972 (and published in 1992) is freely available on my website. See my profile for the website details.

Comment: Your insight is very helpful.

Comment: @Carol You are most welcome. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 4):

As Nigel J has made clear, Evangelical Christians do not believe a person has to be saved every single day.  When we repent before God and turn to Him, placing our faith in what He has done in Christ Jesus, forgiveness for all past sins is immediately forthcoming.  It is God’s free gift.  At that moment in time, it is Jesus who accepts us, and He will never lose any that God has given to Him.

Here are some Bible verses to encourage and uplift you:

> I have been saved – in the past – from the penalty of sin – by a crucified Saviour: “For in this hope we were saved" (Romans 8:24). “For it is by grace you have been saved, through faith – and this not from yourselves, it is the gift of God” (Romans 2:8).

> I am being saved – in the present – from the power of sin – by a living Saviour: "For the message of the cross is foolishness to those who are perishing, but to us who are being saved it is the power of God" (1 Corinthians 1:18).

> I shall be saved – in the future – from the presence of sin – by a coming Saviour: "Since we have now been justified by his blood, how much more shall we be saved from God's wrath through him!"  (Romans 5:9)

> In the past, God granted us justification, a once-for-all, positional holiness in Christ. Now, God guides us to maturity, a practical, progressive holiness. In the future, God will give us glorification, a permanent, ultimate holiness. These three phases of sanctification separate the believer from the penalty of sin (justification), the power of sin (maturity), and the presence of sin (glorification).   https://www.gotquestions.org/sanctification.html

God is love, and God is gracious.  We can rely on His word and in His promises.  The truth sets us free, free from bondage to legalism and to the dictates of men who might seek to control and manipulate others.  We answer only to God and not to any man.  Take heart!  You are loved with an everlasting love (Jeremiah 31:3).

Please note, however, that God's everlasting love is not universal - it's for those who have come to saving faith, people like you and me.

Answer (score 2):

In my answer to this 2019 Stack question, I include a link to another, related, question, and both of those might provide you with some useful information on the topic of saying what has come to be known as "the Sinner's Prayer", to know that one is 'saved'. [What is the biblical basis for “the Sinner’s Prayer” and do Protestants believe that saying the prayer make one a Christian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74721/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-sinner-s-prayer-and-do-protestants-believe/74727#74727)

The simple answer is, "No, Evangelicals do ***not*** think you have to saved every day'.

Answers have already been given as to what the biblical doctrine on being saved is (and is not) so I won't repeat that. By way of conclusion, I want to raise a possibility that might account for unwarranted repetition of an insistence that people keep repeating such a prayer every day.

This is actually the far swing of the pendulum on this topic. It is quite extreme. The usual reaction is to believe that such a prayer only has to be repeated once, and then it can be (basically) forgotten about. A common Evangelical stance is that saying 'the Sinner's Prayer' is key to salvation and 'does the trick' (to put it crudely). Very many Christians are alarmed at that particular Evangelical view, by the way, and much literature has been written exposing what they see as the error of it. However, you do not ask about that. Many Evangelicals, when asked if they are 'born again', cheerfully say, "Oh yes. On [such-and-such a date], I said the Sinner's Prayer, so I'm saved." They might not always remember the exact date, but they usually tell you the location - some big Rally, or in a particular church - occasionally just at home.

That is the usual view, and it is quite opposite to your brother-in-law's view. According to the limited information you have provided, he comes across as obsessive about this, and getting more so as he gets older, perhaps? It may indicate a real insecurity regarding yourself and your offspring, worrying in case what you've said before might not be right, or even that his memory is failing. That he should require such persistent reassurance is most unusual but, really, you don't have to convince anyone on that score, if you know you are, indeed, a Christian.

Comment: My husband was saved, had his own relationship with Jesus, he usually did not come to church with my children and me.  He did not volunteer scripture or ask people if they were saved but if you asked him he was right there with scripture, he knew his bible.On my husband's death bed his brother continually asked if he was saved.  Maybe because I brought the children up the only way I knew in a protestant church.  Both my husband and his brother were Christian Orthodox.Later my brother in law became an Evangelist.

Comment: The children have all chosen Jesus as savior and are leading prosperous christian life's. In my thank you letter to him after the funeral I said my heart was broken into so many pieces and that I am picking up the pieces and praying for God to show me the way.

Comment: @Carol  I understand your pain at your husband having died about 3 months ago. The 5th anniversary of mine is days away. However, this site is different to others in only permitting theological questions and answers - as the box at the top r.h.s. says, personal matters, prayers and counselling are not for here. Your denomination leadership is to be consulted for that. But your theological question has now been answered and this site has many pages related to that topic  which you can benefit from. Do ask other questions if those have not already been covered.

Comment: That was not the question but I will delete.  Thanks.  It won't let me delete but rest assured that the question is about do evangelist believe that you have to be saved more than once and over and over again.  It just happens that my husband his brother dying set this off.  But thanks for reading more into than you needed to.  I am going to get off the site and not log back on

Answer (score 0):

> OP:  Are evangelicals supposed to be saved every day or more than 1 time a day?

How can one be born again and again and again?  Evangelicals understand that a person is born again, one time, forever.  They would follow Jesus Christ.

> Jesus answered and said unto him, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born again, he cannot see the kingdom of God. John 3:3

Even unbelievers understand Jesus met born again once.

> Nicodemus saith unto him, How can a man be born when he is old? can he enter the second time into his mother's womb, and be born? John 3:4

Born again once, not reentering the womb a second, third, or fourth time.

Here is Peter on the issue.

> Being born again, not of corruptible seed, but of incorruptible, by the word of God, which liveth and abideth for ever. ... But the word of the Lord endureth for ever. And this is the word which by the gospel is preached unto you. 1 Peter 1:23, 25

To be sure, there are some religions and cults who teach that you must be saved over and over, but not evangelicals.  Perhaps the OP should take a closer look at the pamphlet presented.

Comment: Would you like me to send you the pamphlet?  Perhaps you are not understanding what I am asking.  My brother in law has been fine with my religious believes and salvation until I wrote him a thank you note after the passing of my husband in October, that I told him my heart is broken into so many pieces and that I hurt everyday, but I am picking up the pieces and asking God to lead me.  He responded that many women in his church are widows and that they no longer hurt as they have accepted Jesus as their savior.  The pamphlet was for me to accept Jesus for my salvation, with him knowing me

Comment: 36 years and attending church with me my children, being there for the christenings and them accepting Jesus as their savior, this was something that I had not seen before.  I called my oldest son and he said his Uncle had always been like that with him making him recite that he is inviting Jesus in his heart over and over, the other 2 children verified this too.  I never knew he did that until I asked because he was now telling me to get saved.  Do you think he forgot that he has gone through the salvation with my children since they were teens?

Comment: @Carol like I said, some believe you must be born again and again and again, but the bible says you are born again of incorruptible seed.  It is normal to grieve for a loved one who passes, but rest assured God is with you.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of different tacks to take on this, in addition to the other answers given

### A belief in lost salvation

Not all Christians believe in "Once saved, always saved". In fact, [that's a fairly large theological divide](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7331/33893). I could see your relative thinking that this is the case and having a "daily salvation" doctrine as a bulwark against it. I have never seen any mainline denomination that believes in lost salvation preach this sort of doctrine, however.

### Do it harder so it sticks

Some people don't rest in doctrines like "my grace is sufficient for you" (2 Cor 12:9), so they overcompensate by trying to "out-Christian" everything. They make everything under the sun about Jesus, Christianity, etc. Thus, in their minds, we might need to be saved every day, because lesser Christians might slip up and lose theirs.

Again, no mainline Christian denomination teaches such a thing.